# angular autocomplete material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Please help me to fix my error. I want to add a `autocomplete` material with a filter to my form.

**.ts** file :

```
  contactArray;
  selectedContact: IContact;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredContact: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private contactservice:ContactService,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filteredContact = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.contactArray.slice())
    );
    this.contactservice.getcontacts().subscribe(
      Response=>this.contactArray=Response
          );
  }
  displayFn(user?: IContact): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): IContact[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.contactArray.filter(contact => contact.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

and my **html** file :

```
<mat-card>
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let contact of filteredContact | async" [value]="contact">
          {{contact.name}}{{contact.family}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

my interface :

```
export interface IContact {
    cid:number;
    name:string;
    family:string;
    email:string;
    phone:number;
}
```

my **service** for read in json-server :

```
  url="http://localhost:3000/contacts";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getcontacts(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }

  addcontacts(contact:IContact){
    return this.http.post(this.url,contact);
  }
}
```

my error is :

> **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined**

Answer (score 2):

The Error message "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" stating that the value of
the variable 'contactArray' is not an array.

Try to declare the type of variable 'contactArray' to Array like this:

your ts file :

```
 contactArray: Array<Object> = [];
  selectedContact: IContact;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredContact: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private contactservice:ContactService,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filteredContact = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.contactArray.slice())
    );
    this.contactservice.getcontacts().subscribe(
      Response=>this.contactArray=Response
          );
  }
  displayFn(user?: IContact): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): IContact[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.contactArray.filter(contact => contact.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have errorr:   (property) UpdateContactComponent.contactArray: Object[]
Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?ts(2322)
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2696)

Comment: Can you share ss of  "this.contactservice.getcontacts().subscribe(
      Response=>this.contactArray=Response
          );" - the Response value in console.

Comment: Is the response object is coming like this [ {'value':value},{value':value}] or [data : {'value':value},{value':value}]

Comment: 0: {id: 1, cid: 11, name: "majid", family: "bagheri", email: "majid@bagheri.ir", …} and more...

Comment: Okay so its coming as object. and you need to convert it to array in order to use slice function.

Comment: How do i do it?